# R calculating hourly mean, and then daily mean from the hourly means

Tags: r

I have some trading data with time and price. I want to take hourly mean price and then use that to calculate daily mean price. Then I want to take that daily mean price and use it to calculate hourly difference from the daily mean price.

So far, I know how to get the hourly mean price with `tapply(df$price, df$dayHour, mean)`. I don't know the best way to get the rest though, especially daily mean.

```
        price               time       hour       dayHour
        (dbl)              (time)     (chr)         (chr)
1  0.00204944 2016-01-07 23:59:02        23 2016-01-07-23
2  0.00205699 2016-01-07 23:58:31        23 2016-01-07-23
3  0.00205699 2016-01-07 23:58:16        23 2016-01-07-23
4  0.00205698 2016-01-07 23:58:12        23 2016-01-07-23
```

Comment: Put your data into an xts object and then used `xts::apply.daily`.